# How to fix error 822 unexpected token at "json"?

Tags: json, vba, api, shopify

I have a VBA file that has been working for years with a POST to API function to create products on Shopify. It has suddenly and for non identified reason stopped working around April 15th 2019. It gives the following error:

> "error": "822: unexpected token at [my JSON string]

This is what the JSON string looks like (you can find a more complete one at the end of this post):

```
{
  "product": {
    "title": "Lunettes",
    "body_html": "some long text",
    "vendor": "Tom Ford",
    "product_type": "lunettes enfant adolescents",
    "published": false,
    "tags": "some tags",
    "variants": [
      {
        "option1": "default title",
        "price": "199",
        "sku": "1",
        "weight_unit": "g"
      }
    ],
    "options": [
      {
        "name": "title",
        "position": 1,
        "values": [
          "default title"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I have already tried:

- check the URL with correct API key and token/password
- tried adding the latest released Shopify API version to the CURL : 2019-04
- check the syntax of the JSON string (comas, {, etc)

Basically tried everything I knew. Please help if you have any clue.

the more complete Json_String is :

```
{"product":{"title":"Lunettes TF5501 ","body_html":"TEXT,<div style=\"text-align: center;\"><img alt=\"Dimensions Lunettes Varionet TF5501 Argent\" src=\"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0855/6878/files/Lunettes.png?15354686291941720795\" style=\"float: none; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\" /></div><div style=\"overflow-x: auto;\"> <table width=\"100%\"> <tbody><tr style=\"background-color: #98ffaf;\"><td style=\"text-align: center;\">140 mm</td><td style=\"text-align: center;\">54 mm</td><td style=\"text-align: center;\">38 mm</td><td style=\"text-align: center;\">18 mm</td><td style=\"text-align: center;\">145 mm</td></tr></tbody></table></div>","vendor":"Brand","product_type":"lunettes anti lumière bleue","published":false,"tags":"meta-filter-Marque-Varionet,meta-filter-Forme-Rectangle,meta-filter-Genre-Unisex,meta-filter-Genre-Homme,meta-filter-Genre-Femme,meta-filter-Couleur-Argent","variants":[{"option1":"default title","price":"199","sku":"tom ford tf5501016","position":1,"grams":"100","inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"339","fulfillment_service":"logisticien-mavu","inventory_management":"shopify","option_1":"default title","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"inventory_quantity":1,"weight_unit":"g"}],"options":[{"name":"title","position":1,"values":["default title"] }]
}}
```

Thanks!

Youri

Comment: Often you can have an accidentally added a character that is read by the parser and screws things up but you cannot easily see it. This error is not from Shopify but instead is originating in your request code. Double check your data for weird characters.

Also, someone else with the same problem solved it by fixing their headers. Ensure yours are correct too. 

https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/error-gt-822-unexpected-token-at-price-rule/td-p/480430

Comment: it would help to see the actual code (without your personal credentials)

Answer (score 0):

The first JSON you provided (please correct it to a code-block) is correct, but when parsing your more complete Json_string, you'll see that you have too much curly brackets at the end:

```
{
    "product": {
        "title": "Lunettes TF5501 ",
        "body_html": "TEXT,https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0855/6878/files/Lunettes.png?15354686291941720795\" style=\"float: none; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\" /> 140 mm54 mm38 mm18 mm145 mm",
        "vendor": "Brand",
        "product_type": "lunettes anti lumière bleue",
        "published": false,
        "tags": "meta-filter-Marque-Varionet,meta-filter-Forme-Rectangle,meta-filter-Genre-Unisex,meta-filter-Genre-Homme,meta-filter-Genre-Femme,meta-filter-Couleur-Argent",
        "variants": [{
            "option1": "default title",
            "price": "199",
            "sku": "tom ford tf5501016",
            "position": 1,
            "grams": "100",
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": "339",
            "fulfillment_service": "logisticien-mavu",
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "option_1": "default title",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": true,
            "inventory_quantity": 1,
            "weight_unit": "g"
        }],
        "options": [{
            "name": "title",
            "position": 1,
            "values": ["default title"]
        }]
    }
}
}
}
```

Try removing the last 2 curly brackets

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, sorry for the 2 extras curly brackets  it was a typo. I have removed them from the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies

@David : I've seen the link https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/error-gt-822-unexpected-token-at-price-rule/td-p/480430 , but i don't understand where and how i must use the 'X-Shopify-Access-Token' in VBA code, should it be added in the objHTTP.setRequestHeader? This is the API key, the Password or the "shared secret" ?

@QHarr : my posting parameters are :

```
Dim result As String
Dim objHTTP As Object
Url = "http://API-KEY:PASSWORD@SHOP-NAME.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-04/products.json"

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

objHTTP.Open "POST", Url, False, "API-KEY", "PASSWORD"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"


objHTTP.send ("json_string")

result = objHTTP.responseText
```